# Can't run python 3.3.3 on CentOS nonGUI environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, centos5

Well I have a question about running python 3.3.3 on CentOS. I installed using this guide:
http://toomuchdata.com/2012/06/25/how-to-install-python-2-7-3-on-centos-6-2/. But instead of downloading 3.3.0 in downloaded 3.3.3 from this link: [www.python.org/ftp/python/3.3.3/Python-3.3.3.tgz](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.3.3/Python-3.3.3.tgz). So i used:

```
wget www.python.org/ftp/python/3.3.3/Python-3.3.3.tgz
tar xvzf file.tgz
cd Python-3.3.3
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make && make altinstall
```

When I run python using command *python* I'm still in 2.6.6 (It was on CentOS already before) instead of 3.3.3. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have to start python 3.x with

```
python3
```

Answer (score 0):

What I've normally done with my production systems is put `/usr/local/bin/` in the `$PATH` which is where I end up compiling Python (*2.7 in my case*) on CentOS systems.

Also remember that other versions of Python are normally "suffixed", so start it with:

```
$ python3.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method to install Python on Centos 7

https://medium.com/@gchandra/customize-centos-7-x-with-python-3-x-c7c575d53c9a